# Append field to the end of an array

Tags: php

I have an array, and when i `echo` it i get the following output;

```
Array[{"name":"Kat","age":"10"}]
```

Now, i need to add an additional filed into this; so finally it should appear as;

```
Array[{"message":"Success","name":"Kat","age":"10"}]
```

if `$arr` is my array, how am i going to append `"message":"Success"` ?

Sorry, i don't have any code to demonstrate my workings, i am stuck here. i would appreciate it if anyone can help me.

Comment: $arr['message']='Success'; looks like your json_encoding $arr

Comment: Yes i am encoding it to a JSON

Comment: So it wouldn't really matter if the new element was at the start or end as suggested below and in your example (but good to know)

Comment: Yeah, that will not be a issue. i just want to append it to that array and output it as a JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array content looks like JSON to me. But, if your array are actually just PHP arrays, then do:

```
$arr = array('name' => 'Kat', 'age' => '10');
$arr['message'] = 'Success';
```

If it is a JSON encoded array:

```
$arr = json_decode('{"name":"Kat","age":"10"}' , true)); //true decodes to an array and not a standard object
$arr['message'] = 'Success';

echo $arr;

//If you want it back in JSON
$json = json_encode($arr);
echo $json;
```

Answer (score 1):

Like Waygood said if you want to add a value to the end of an array just use:

`$array[] = $value;` or `$array['somekey'] = $somevalue;`

However, if you need to add a value to the beginning of the array (like your example) you can use:

`array_unshift($array, $value);`

Alternatively, if you need to add a key and a value to the beginning you can simply make an array with the key => value pair and merge the two arrays like so:

`$firstArray = array("message" => "Success");`

`$newArray = array_merge($firstArray, $secondArray);`

For reference, here are the links to the php.net documentation:

[array_unshift](https://www.php.net/array_unshift)

[array_merge](https://www.php.net/array_merge)

Answer (score 0):

what about `$arr["message"]="Success";`?

Answer (score 0):

To add a named field, you can just use this:

```
$array['message'] = 'Success';
```

To add a unnamed field, this is the way to do it:

```
$array[] = $value;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of doing it.

PHP array functions

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

The + operator

Or like others mentioned using $arg['var'] =

Just define "message":"Success" as another array and use push, merge or +

Also looks like you have it Json encoded. You will need to handle that as well.

The array functions only work with regular arrays, not encoded strings.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$arr = array("name"=>"Kat","age"=>"10");
print_r($arr);
$arr = array_merge(array("message" => "Success"), $arr);
print_r($arr);
```