# Get the value of an Array

Tags: php

i have an `Array`, when i print it i get the following output;

```
Array[{"city":"London","school":"st patrick"}]
```

Now i want to read the item saved in variable `city` and check if its `London` in the `IF` condition below;

```
if ($cityArray['city'] == 'London') {

  echo 'City present';
}
```

My if condition above, is incorrect, i am not getting the expected output. I guess the way i am accessing the `city` item is incorrect.

Comment: This results in an error

Comment: Use correct syntax, or is that the problem? You're missing `$` on `$cityArray`

Comment: That's an error, i will correct it

Comment: Looks more like JavaScript. (or JSON in any case)

Comment: This question seems really similiar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11466703/append-field-to-the-end-of-an-array/11466803#11466803 for some reason. :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things. Your array looks to be JSON format. You'll want to decode using json_decode (after fixing the format of the array):

```
$jsonArray = Array('{"city":"London","school":"st patrick"}'); // User the correct PHP array format: Array() while the inside elements should be quoted if they're strings.
$cityArray = json_decode($jsonArray[0]);
```

Use the correct variable reference format:

```
if ($cityArray->city == 'London') { // $cityArray is an object, so you'll need to use the -> operator to get its "city" property.
    echo 'City present';
}
```

The way you're trying to access the value of the associative array (by inputting the name to return the value) is correct, but just need to fix a couple of formatting issues, is all.

Edit: Added index number of array to get the JSON.

Comment: it says, json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in

Comment: @Illep Sorry, my mistake. I've added the index number 0 for the JSON array so that it gets the string of JSON (I know that PHP 5.4 supports the new array format but I'm not super familiar with it as of yet).

Answer (score 0):

This is a JSON string, you need to decode it first:

```
$data = json_decode($json);
```

Then you can access the elements like so:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++) {
    $element = $data[$i];
    echo $element->city;
}
```